# Requirements for setting margin to auto

Tags: html, css, image, margin

I have the following html:

```
<div id="img_holder">
    <img id="image" src="../../images/img1.jpg" />
</div>
```

It has the following css:

```
#img_holder {
    background-color:#EC0610;
    min-height: 500px;
    float:left;
    width: 550px;
}

#image {
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

The image's margins aren't being set but its padding is. Also, when I set the margin to a specific value, the margins work. When I use the element inspector in Google Chrome, that line in the styles window doesn't have a line through it so I'm assuming it's valid css. I just can't figure out why it won't get set to auto.

Comment: What are you trying to do? center the image?

Comment: Add `display:block;` to the image, or `text-align:center;` to the image holder (thus removing in the latter case `margin:auto;` from the image).

Comment: You do understand that margins do not work on inline elements, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the image to `display:block;`

demo http://jsfiddle.net/mCen7/

```
#image {
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: strangely the fiddle leads to something completely different

Comment: @Vector - Wrong Fiddle link. :) Fixed for you,

Comment: thanks @Paulie_D i've got so many fiddles open, i must have pasted the wrong url (maybe it's time for bed :/)

Comment: In fact, for the [inline image](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins), *A computed value of `auto` for `margin-left` or `margin-right` becomes a used value of `0`*

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you. I didn't know images were displayed inline.

Answer (score 1):

I would appreciate you give us your actual objective.

As far as I understand, you simply want the img to be centered in your div.

img tags are inline tags, that is, share the behavior of a text or a letter. It's not a block, such as a div.

inline tags are horizontally centered like text, with a text-align: center style, as follows:

```
#img_holder {
    background-color:#EC0610;
    min-height: 500px;
    float:left;
    width: 550px;
    text-align: center;
}

#image {
    width: 300px;
    height: 450px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
<div id="img_holder">
    <img id="image" src="../../images/img1.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't more detailed it's that I find the process of spacing everything out to paste code rather tedious. I would have preferred to supply all my code. But anyways the goal was just for the image to be centered in the div. Setting the image to block display did the trick.